# Instantiating text elements of correct type SVGTextElement before appending

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, d3.js

I need to instantiate several text elements programmatically from given data. These text elements should be surrounded by a rectangle that has the width of the text element with the largest width. Like this:

[image]

At the moment, I am using a method to create the textnode, that looks like this:

```js
let textnodes = data.map(d => {
  let svgText = document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces['svg'],'text')
  let textNode = document.createTextNode(d.text)

  svgText.appendChild(textNode)
  return svgText
})
```

Afterwards, I compute the width and finally apply a maximum function, where `getTextWidth` is a self-made method:

```js
Math.max(...textnodes.map(t=> {
      return t.firstChild ? this.getTextWidth(
        t.firstChild.nodeValue,
        this.config.attributesFontSize + "px " + this.config.attributesFont ) : 0
    }))
```

My question is: Is there a way to create a `SVGTextElement` provided as a type from D3 instead of using `document.createElementNS(...)`? The reason I am asking is, that `SVGTextElement` gives me the possibility to use the `getBBox()` method that gives me the `width` property for free. Ideally I would like to instantiate my text nodes like this:

```js
data.map({ d => 
  let text = new SVGTextElement()
  text.setAttribute(...)
  ...
})
```

However, using the constructor like this is not permitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to the problem:

1. The first possible solution to this is casting the result—in terms of TypeScript called [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)—to `SVGTextElement` because you know that your call to `document.createElementNS()` is guaranteed to yield exactly that type:

   ```
    const svgText = document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces['svg'], "text") as SVGTextElement;
   ```
2. There is, however, a more elegant solution to this by letting the compiler do the work for you. In the [DOM type definitions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts) for the [`.createElementNS`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4480-L4484) method there is an [overload](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4481) especially for creating elements in the SVG namespace:

   ```
    createElementNS<K extends keyof SVGElementTagNameMap>(namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", qualifiedName: K): SVGElementTagNameMap[K];
   ```

   In this definition the [`SVGElementTagNameMap`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18154-L18218) is an interface mapping all element names of the SVG namespace to the corresponding type. Thus, the above type definition is to be read as: If the `namespaceURI` is exactly `"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` and the `qualifiedName` is a key contained in the `SVGElementTagNameMap` interface then the compiler infers the return type to be the element type referred to by the `qualifiedName` in that interface.

   ```
    const svgText = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
   ```

   For the above line the `svgText` will be of type `SVGTextElement` just as you need it to be.

   Side note: for some reasons that elude me, you have to specify the namespace as a string, you cannot refer to the string by `d3.namespaces.svg` or any other reference. Maybe someone could fill in the missing information to further improve this answer.
3. If you want a D3-ish solution you can use [`d3.create()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#create) which will create a detached element and return a new selection containg that single element. The compiler will not be able to automatically infer the type, though, because you need to specify `svg:` as the prefix for the SVG namespace. You can, however, resort to generics to specify the type as can be seen from the [type defintion](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts#L1081) for the method:

   ```
    export function create<NewGElement extends Element>(name: string): Selection<NewGElement, undefined, null, undefined>;
   ```

   Your code could look like this:

   ```
    const svgTextSel = create<SVGTextElement>("svg:text");
   ```